# np.array_split gives ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size -

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm currently working with time series data and was trying to use the `np.array_split` to split my data into batches.

To give a bit more detail, I originally had a DataFrame that's of size `(32000, 149)`. I handled this data so that I could create a sliding window of size `(100, 40)` over the data and use that in an autoregressive fashion. Each "minibatch" has 32 instances, each of size `(100, 40)` which leads me to a total of 1,000 of these so-called minibatches.

What I want to do is divide these 1,000 batches into the "number of days," which in this case would be 10, meaning that each separate "day-batch" would contain 100 minibatches, respectively.

The code that I have is the following:

```
data = {}
batches = []
minibatches = []
count = 1

for idx, _ in df.iterrows():
    minibatches.append(df.iloc[idx:(idx + 100), 0:40])
    if count == 32:
        batches.append(minibatches)
        minibatches = []
        count = 0
    count += 1

num_days = len(batches) // 100 # 1000 // 100 = 10
batch_split = np.array_split(batches, num_days)

for day in range(num_days):
    data[fold][day] = batch_split[day] # Nevermind the "fold" variable here.
```

The error that I'm getting for the `np.array_split` line is:

```
ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 100 to array axis with dimension 40
```

If I were to break down the `batches` variable, it's simply a list containing 1,000 lists. These 1,000 lists are the aforementioned minibatches, and are also lists containing 32 DataFrames each. Each DataFrame of the 32 DataFrames is of size `(100, 40)`.

I don't understand where the `size 100` and `dimension 40` is coming from in this setting. I'm not accessing the DataFrame values, and simply want to split the list `batches`.

Comment: Any particular reason why you’re appending and splitting instead of using masks and indexing? Also, some example data and output would go a long way towards finding a good solution!

Comment: I’m also quite curious as to what kind of data is still meaningful when you treat different groups of columns identically, since your “miniminibatches” are of size (100,40). Are your slices/groups overlapping? Hope that made sense :)

Answer (score 0):

Try making sure the collection you are passing into the function is a numpy array.

```
batch_split = np.array_split(np.array(batches), num_days)
```

My best guess at an explanation is since you are collecting everything in a list which has no attribute 'shape', it's finding the 'shape' attribute on the dataframes.